# glassfish full gc once an hour

Tags: java, garbage-collection, glassfish

I'm seeing a full GC about once an hour in our Glassfish application.  Extract from the GC log:

```
9.210: [Full GC 28311K->27979K(6422528K), 0.3770238 secs]
...
3609.647: [Full GC 1186957K->597880K(6478208K), 4.5102977 secs]
...
7214.192: [Full GC 742184K->595596K(6469504K), 4.3726625 secs]
...
10818.805: [Full GC 756228K->570803K(6455936K), 4.8630472 secs]
```

And this pattern roughly repeats as long as Glassfish is up.  The "..." in between are incremental GCs.  The timing seems awfully suspicious- why would we be seeing full GC's about once an hour?

JVM startup parameters:

```
-Xms6400m
-Xmx6400m
-XX:NewSize=1024m
-XX:MaxNewSize=1024m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:+UseParallelOldGC
-Xloggc:C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\gc\gc.log
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-Xss1024k
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

According to JVisualVM, we're no where close to running out of heap space.

Glassfish 3.1.2.2, Oracle JDK 1.6.0_45, Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect your RMI is triggering a Full clean up.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html

both

> sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval
>
> When it is necessary to ensure that unreachable remote objects are unexported and garbage collected in a timely fashion, the value of this property represents the maximum interval (in milliseconds) that the Java RMI runtime will allow between garbage collections of the local heap. The default value is 3600000 milliseconds (one hour).

and

> sun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval
>
> When it is necessary to ensure that DGC clean calls for unreachable remote references are delivered in a timely fashion, the value of this property represents the maximum interval (in milliseconds) that the Java RMI runtime will allow between garbage collections of the local heap. The default value is 3600000 milliseconds (one hour).

default to hourly checks.

I would set these to a day or a week for you believe you don't need these.

Comment: I did try setting those intervals to 1 day.  Interestingly, full GC's went down to less frequent interval, but still more often than one day.  There was one about 10 seconds after startup, then one about 4 hours later, and then one about 45 minutes after that, and I haven't seen any since then.

Comment: @Jeff The remaining Full GCs might be actually needed, then. You might want to add `-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure` to get more details and context in the GC logs.

Comment: I suggest you increase you heap size and memory profile your code to reduce the amount of garbage you are creating.  In extreme cases, you can get to the point where the application is not GCing for a whole day. http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-avoid-garbage-collection.html

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to disable explicit GC (`-XX:+DisableExplicitGC`) and see if the FullGCs go away.

Comment: I'm aware of this option but wary of using it.  My understanding is that the JVM will normally perform incremental GC's, but sometimes full GC's are necessary to "catch up" if incremental GC's aren't keeping up.  If so, then it seems that completely disabling full GC's might be harmful if the JVM ever gets into that state...

Comment: @Jeff it doesn't disable full GCs, only *explicit* GCs (`System.gc()`). The JVM will trigger a full GC if it needs to, regardless of that setting.  With an Oracle JDK 6+, the explicit GCs appear in the GC log with `Full GC (System)` instead of simply `Full GC`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification.  I've never seen "Full GC (System)" in our GC logs.  And we never call System.gc() from our code.